# Search for a key for a given value in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have this dictionary below

```
metric_app_mapper = \
    {"appdynamics":
        {
            "avgresptime": ["average response time", "avgresptime", "avgrest", "art"],
            "callspermin": ["calls per minute", "callspermin", "calls/min"],
            "allapps": ["all apps", "all apps info", "all applications"]
        },
     "another_software":
         {
             "metric": ["synonyms"]
         }
    }
```

I am trying to get the key for the value **"art"**. But I am only able to search for the value **"art"** or the list it is in. Here is my code below

```
search_key = [j for i in metric_app_mapper.values() for j in i.values() for k in j if k == "art"]
print("Key found", search_key)
```

I get the list for the given value

```
Key found [['average response time', 'avgresptime', 'avgrest', 'art']]
```

How do I get the associated key in this case **"avgresptime"** for the given list I found for the value and in turn it's given key which is **"Appdynamics"**? Is there any better way to do it since my approach involves O(n^3) runnning time?

Comment: Something like: `[k for d in metric_app_mapper.values() for k, v in d.items() if 'art' in v]`... (untested)

Comment: @JonClements wow!It does gives me the subkey which is "avgresptime"!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive solution that yields key "paths".  The `(*keys, k)` syntax is available in Python versions >= 3.5, you can also use `keys + (k,)`

```
from collections.abc import Collection

def find(dictionary, value, keys=()):
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        path_to = (*keys, k)
        if v == value:
            yield path_to
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from find(v, value, path_to)
        elif isinstance(v, Collection): # might make more sense to use Container, I'm not sure
            if value in v:
                yield path_to


print(list(find(metric_app_mapper, 'art')))
# [('appdynamics', 'avgresptime')]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a little modifcation to @Jon Clements code, this is what gives me what I need.

```
interpreted_tool = [[k1, k2] for k1, v1 in metric_app_mapper.items() for k2, v2 in v1.items() for v3 in v2 if v3 == metric]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
for i,j in metric_app_mapper.items():
    for k,l in j.items():
        if "art" in l:
            print(k,i)
```